# ¿Como puede ejecutar una funcion despues de cierto tiempo en ionic?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic, rxjs

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero que cuando termine un determinado tiempo se ejecute una función no importando en que vista se encuentre, actualmente puse un timer en app.component.ts pero no funciona.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado .

Comment: A que se refiere con "poner un timer" que codigo usó?

Answer (score 0):

Con poner en el oninit un setTimeout debería bastar

Comment: En el appModule.ts o en que archivo